# date format in crystal reports

Tags: mysql, crystal-reports

I have a report having command object like this. My back end is `MYSQL`.
I'm not getting data in designer with the below query:

```
SELECT * FROM clock_time 
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(
DATE_FORMAT(clock_time,'%d-%m-%Y %H:%i'),'%d-%m-%Y %H:%i') = 
DATE_FORMAT('2014-06-19 11:03:43','%d-%m-%Y %H:%i')
```

What is the mistake I am doing?

Comment: why dont use `SELECT * FROM clock_time WHERE clock_time='2014-06-19 11:03:43';` and one more thing `clock_time` is column in table `clock_time`?

Comment: Hi catalinetu I need to omit the seconds part from the date time I am giving

Comment: Yes its a column in the table

Comment: and what is your column data type and please give an example

Comment: Hi column is a time stamp.Format is like this 2014-09-10 11:17:02.But I want only 2014-09-10 11:17

Comment: Are u getting any records when run the same query in mysql.....not through crystal reports

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is what you should do

```
SELECT * FROM clock_time 
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(clock_time,'%d/%m/%Y %H:%i')='10/09/2014 11:17';
```

Comment: Hi I need to omit the seconds part and I want the format like this  10/09/2014 11:17 .And also the hard coded value is a parameter from crystal reports.Please suggest